# Why does my code print both if and else statement in finding max num between them and if i put a >b?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am trying to find max number between two inputs and conditions that I have used were :

1. if (a>b) : a is greater than b
2. if(a==b) : both are equal
3. else : b is greater than a

Now, if I take a = 10 and b = 20, I get : b is greater than a, which is true.

However, when I take a = 30 and b = 5, I get both the statements like : a is greater than b, b is greater than a, which means both the statements of if(a>b) and of else{} are getting printed.

When I search on Google then they have written if(a>=b) as the first expression. Now my question is, what the "=" is making difference for executing the way we want it, and why by only adding ">" I am getting both the statements executed?

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;

public class conditional {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter first number : ");
     int a = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Enter second number : ");
     int b = sc.nextInt();

     if(a>b)
     {
      System.out.println("the greatest number is " + a);
     }
     if(a==b)
     {
      System.out.println("both are equal numbers");
     }
     else{
      System.out.println("the greatest number is " + b);
     }
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyoTh.png)

Comment: The `else` clause only applies to `if(a==b)` , maybe what you need is `else if(a==b)` .

Comment: You need `else if (a == b)`. a > b prints for 30, then you're checking if numbers are equal, which are not, so the else branch prints for 5.

Answer (score 6):

Your `if (a > b)` statement is *entirely* separate from the following statements. Here's a way of demonstrating that, adding more code between the two:

```java
if (a > b) {
    System.out.println("the greatest number is " + a);
}

System.out.println("Note how unrelated the code before and after is...");

if (a == b) {
    System.out.println("both are equal numbers");
} else {
    System.out.println("the greatest number is " + b);
}
```

Your list of conditions would be more clearly written as:

- if (a>b) : a is greater than b
- *Otherwise*, if(a==b) : both are equal
- *Otherwise*, b is greater than a

That makes it clear that you actually need an "else if" in the middle:

```java
if (a > b) {
    System.out.println("the greatest number is " + a);
} else if (a == b) {
    System.out.println("both are equal numbers");
} else {
    System.out.println("the greatest number is " + b);
}
```

At this point, the three branches are tightly linked to each other - you can't put that extra statement before "else if" (but outside the first "if" block) because the "else if" is joined to the first "if".

Answer (score 1):

your condition of putting things are wrong .

```
 if(a>b)
     {
      System.out.println("the greatest number is " + a);
     }
```

30>5(True so it runs)
Now for below case only it works as if..else statement.

```
 if(a==b)
     {
      System.out.println("both are equal numbers");
     }
 else{
  System.out.println("the greatest number is " + b);
 }
```

So you should be using

```
if(a>b)
     {
      System.out.println("the greatest number is " + a);
     }
     else if(a==b)
     {
      System.out.println("both are equal numbers");
     }
     else{
      System.out.println("the greatest number is " + b);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use this to run your code effectively

```
if(a>b)
 {
  System.out.println("the greatest number is " + a);
 }
 else if(a==b)
 {
  System.out.println("both are equal numbers");
 }
 else{
  System.out.println("the greatest number is " + b);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using `switch` (once learned, if allowed?!) like in:

```
String message = switch (Integer.signum(Integer.compare(a, b))) {
    case +1 -> "the greatest number is " + a;
    case  0 -> "both are equal numbers";
    case -1 -> "the greatest number is " + b;
    default -> throw new RuntimeException("shoudl never happen!");
};
```

`compare(a, b)` will return a number that is:

- negative, if `a < b`;
- zero, if both are equal;
- positive, if `a > b`.

Actually it is returning `-1`, `0`, or `+1`; but that is not how it is specified. Since the `switch` requires discrete values (unless we use Pattern Matching), we use `signum()` which only returns these three values, that is,
`signum(x)` will return:

- `-1` if the argument is negative (`x < 0`);
- `0` if the argument is zero;
- `+1` if the argument is positive (`x > 0`);

A `switch` is often ideal if we have multiple exclusive option. In this particular case, it is a matter of preference, mainly regarding readability, if a `switch` should be used instead of `if-else` combinations. Sure one must also know what this methods are doing and why these are being used - `a > b` is more *directly* expressing the intentions.